Drainage problems and solutions for gravel Driveway?
We have a section of front yard we want to turn into a gravel driveway. The problem is that it is in a low spot, but also beside a private road that has terrible drainage as well. I came up with two potential solutions.
One, a French drain with a catch basin to take the water to the backyard and discharge there. The only issue is that it would go slightly against the yard grade before getting to the back.
The second would be to install a Geo cell system, so I could use clean gravel instead of minus and let the water drain through the gravel while having the gravel stay in place.
Which would be better, or does anyone have any more thoughts or ideas?
P.S. I am trying to avoid letting the water cross the road due to the fact that the pothole at the end of the road is already catching a lot of water and is going to be filled in soon as well. The private road has terrible drainage, with no storm drains or even ditching to direct water. Including some pictures to show the low spot and the road. 

Dig a trench through the yard which gives sufficient slope to ignore the existing grade.

If it weren't for that private road's poor drainage, would you have a problem?  If not, does your zoning code prohibit its owner from allowing runoff onto adjacent property?  If so, you may have recourse.  If you do, you might ask them to fix it, contribute to your cost if you fix it, or let you use their road to get to your backyard (if it runs parallel to your proposed driveway; I'm not clear on the layout).
